# Use custom authorization method as default for all endpoints but not on Blazor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to implement a custom authorization method so that it is applied to api endpoints by default but does not affect the blazor pages in the same application. I also want this to allow other authorizations to be added to individual endpoints such as `[AllowAnonymous]`.

I want it to be applied to all endpoints by default so that no one ever forgets to apply the authorization creating a gap in security so using `[Authorization]` in each method or class is not what I am looking for.

All of my api endpoints are accessed through `/api/route` and are in the folder `api`.

How can I apply my custom authoriation methods to all api endpoints only and not to blazor pages?

Currently, my authorization method works when the following is added to program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "EndpointAuthenticatedUser").Build();
});
```

This also affects the blazor pages and makes then inaccessible.

Adding the following to blazor pages does not work as the blazor pages are still inaccessible.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

I have also tried to add the following to program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Token", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "EndpointAuthenticatedUser");
    });
});

...

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("Token");
```

This, when using breakpoints to step through my code, looks like the authorization policy is being used but the authentication never fails so is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of Middleware and Authorization Policy to achieve this functionality.

Would you like to welcome my approach below?

1. First, define your custom authorization policy:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "EndpointAuthenticatedUser");
    });
});
```

2. Now, you can apply this policy only to your API endpoints. This can be achieved by creating a middleware and checking the request path:

```cs
public class ApiAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _policyName;

    public ApiAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string policyName)
    {
        _next = next;
        _policyName = policyName;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
        {
            var authzUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "") }, "Custom"));
            var authzResult = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(authzUser, null, _policyName);

            if (!authzResult.Succeeded)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync();
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

3. Now, you can apply this middleware in your pipeline:

```cs
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddleware<ApiAuthorizationMiddleware>("ApiPolicy");
});
```

This code will use your custom policy for every endpoint that starts with "/api". If the user is not authorized, it will send a challenge response.

This setup will ignore Blazor pages as they do not follow the "/api" path.

Please remember to register your middleware before app.UseEndpoints but after app.UseAuthentication and app.UseAuthorization to ensure the authentication process executes before your middleware.

If you still have any problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: This very nearly worked thanks. It took me a bit to figure out how to get the claim from my authorization method rather than setting up a new ClaimsPrincipal but now it is working!

Comment: did you use chatgpt at all to write this answer?